# What is PERFORM_ACTION action type inside redux?

Tags: redux

Inside my Redux store I recently started getting PERFORM_ACTION actions, which wrap my actual actions as follows:

```
{
    type: PERFORM_ACTION,
    action: {
        type: REAL_ACTION,
        payload: 123
    }
}
```

I was not able to find any answer to this pattern neither in the documentations, nor in Google. The only suggestions that Google included were just references to this type of action without any explanation of what is it and why does it appear in applications.

So, what is this action?

Comment: You should add your reducer and action code. Without it, its almost impossible to tell. It sure looks weird being enveloped like that. The `action` should just be the payload. Also, add your package.json, maybe you added a wrapper library recently.

Answer (score 5):

redux dev tool extension wrap your actions with it's own action, what you can do is change the order of the middlewares load,

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            /* ----  middlewares ----  */

        ),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    )
);
```

if you place the the redux devtools middleware before your middlewares, you will get the warped action.